# Card Footer button

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am learning ASP.NET Core and Razor pages, I already did a project, and the simplicity is amazing.

Anyway, I am building a form in a card, And I want my order button to take all the with of the footer.

I already went to the documentation but I didn't find any reference to do this.

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post">

            <div class="form-group row mt-5 mb-2">
                <label class="col-sm-2 ">Pizza name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Pizzas.PizzaName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.TomatoSauce" placeholder="Tomato Sauce" />Tomato Sauce
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Peperoni" placeholder="Peperoni" />Peperoni
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Cheese" placeholder="Cheese" />Cheese
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Muchroom" placeholder="Muchroom" />Muchroom
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Beef" placeholder="Beef" />Beef
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Pineaple" placeholder="Pineaple" />Pineaple
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Ham" placeholder="Ham" />Ham
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Tuna" placeholder="Tuna" />Tuna
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Order</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put form outside `card-body` and `card-footer`:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    <form method="post">
    <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group row mt-5 mb-2">
                <label class="col-sm-2 ">Pizza name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Pizzas.PizzaName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.TomatoSauce" placeholder="Tomato Sauce" />Tomato Sauce
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Peperoni" placeholder="Peperoni" />Peperoni
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Cheese" placeholder="Cheese" />Cheese
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Muchroom" placeholder="Muchroom" />Muchroom
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Beef" placeholder="Beef" />Beef
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Pineaple" placeholder="Pineaple" />Pineaple
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Ham" placeholder="Ham" />Ham
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Pizzas.Tuna" placeholder="Tuna" />Tuna
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Order</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```